# Error when trying to retrieve a term with ajax

Tags: forms, taxonomy-terms, ajax, 9

We are creating a custom form to edit a certain node.
We do this above because there are some things that cannot be accomplished with the default form.

I want to use AJAX to populate the fields of the custom form with the values entered in the existing node, as shown below.

```php
$form['client_company'] = [
  '#type' => 'entity_autocomplete',
  '#target_type' => 'taxonomy_term',
  '#tags' => TRUE,
  '#selection_settings' => array(
    'target_bundles' => array('vid', 'client'),
  ),
  '#weight' => '0',
];
```

```php
$term = $this->taxonomyStroage->load($node->field_project_refercompany->target_id);
$form['client_company']['#value'] = $term;
$response->addCommand(new ReplaceCommand(".form-item-client-company", $form['client_company'])); // Line 208

return $response;
```

However, I get the following error.

> Error: Drupal\Core\Template\Attribute->__toString() in Call to undefined method Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term::render() (/app/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Template/Attribute.php line.324)
> /app/web/modules/custom/projectmanager/src/Form/ProjectManagerForm.php (208): Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse->addCommand(Object(Drupal\Core\Ajax\ReplaceCommand))

I do not know how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code `$term` will be a term entity object.
Try setting the value of the form to the term id.
`$form['client_company']['#value'] = $term->id();`

EDIT:
Actually, it seems you already have the term ID, so you should not need to load the term entity. Maybe just do:
`$form['client_company']['#value'] = $node->field_project_refercompany->target_id`

Comment: Thanks,error not occured.Am I correct in understanding that the entity "term" itself cannot be entered into the form, but only text-based items such as target_id and name can be entered into the form?